# How can I reduce or ignore metamagic costs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, metamagic

I know that there are several ways in which you can reduce the metamagic cost for one particular spell, such as [Spell Perfection](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection/) and [Magic Lineage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/). But are there any ways in Pathfinder to reduce metamagic costs without having to tie it to a specific spell? Is there anything that either simply reduces metamagic cost or exchanges it for something else, such as skill check?

I'm looking for stuff such as class features or feats, not magic items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Wizards

Wizards of the [Universalist school](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/universalist/) gain an ability at 8th level, **Metamagic Mastery**, which allows them to apply the effects of one metamagic feat without increasing the casting time or altering the spell level. This ability can be used once per day at 8th level, then an additional time per day every 2 additional wizard levels (ex: 16th level, 5 times per day).

Also, the [Pact Wizard](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/pact-wizard-wizard-archetype/) archetype is able to reduce the increase from metamagic feats by 1 spell slot, when using their **Great Power, Greater Expense** at 15th. This has a limited use per day (based on her int), but also has other benefits, such as being able to roll twice and pick the best result for caster level, concentration, initiative checks, or saving throws.

### Psychics

11th level [Psychics](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/psychic/) have access to a *Major Amplification* called **Mimic Metamagic**, which allows them to mimic the effects of two chosen metamagic feats when casting their psychic spells by using points from their *phrenic pool*. This does not increase the casting time of the spell, nor the spell level necessary to cast the spell.

### Magic items

*I know you didn't ask for magic items, but Im listing those here for completeness. They are the next easiest way to accomplish that without using optional rules.*

[Metamagic Gems](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gem-metamagic/) are single-use magic items that allow you to apply a metamagic feat's effect to a spell when it's being cast *without altering the spell level*. This means that a *Maximizing Sapphire* can be used to cast a maximized *Fireball* that will still use up a 3rd level slot (assuming sorcerer/wizard).

Similarly, [Metamagic Rods](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/) will allow your character to apply the metamagic effect on the rod on any spell, depending on the level of the rod, without altering the spell's level, but only for a limited number of times per day. A lesser [Maximize Metamagic Rod](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-maximize/) would allow you to maximize up to 3 different spells from levels 1st to 3rd without increasing the spell level, which would recharge the next day.

However, there are even more specific items, that apply the effects of a single metamagic feat to certain spells you cast, like the [Book of Extended Summoning](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/book-of-extended-summoning/).

### Legendary items

[Mythic Adventures](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ywe?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Mythic-Adventures) introduced [Legendary items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic-items/legendary-items/), which have an option to be enchanted with **Metamagician**, which allows you to spend some of the item's *Legendary power* to fuel a metamagic effect you know without increasing the cast time or spell level.

### Mythic powers

Both the [Hierophant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/hierophant/) and the [Archmage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/archmage/) have abilities that allows them to cast spells using some of their mythic power instead of spending the spell slot.

For Hierophants, they use the **Inspired Spell** ability and may cast any spell on their list, even if not memorized, without spending a spell slot and are allowed to apply any metamagic feat they know, as long as it doesn't alter the spell level beyond what you are allowed to cast.

For Archmages, they have a similar ability, **Wild Arcana**, but they also have another ability that can be picked at 3rd tier, **Arcane Metamastery**, which allows them to pick one metamagic feat they know, as long as it only increases the spell level by at most one level (which increases every time they pick this ability), and apply that metamagic feat to any arcane spell they cast for the next 10 rounds.

### Wild magic

One of the examples of *Wild Magic* effects that a spell cast can do using the (optional) [Wild Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/wild-magic-optional-rules/) rules from [Pathfinder Unchained](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/unchained/classes/index.html) is to allow a spellcaster to make a caster level check with a DC of 10 + spell level + 5 per level increase of the metamagic feat they want to use, which then allows casting the spell without increasing the casting time or using a higher level slot. But if she fails on the check, they roll on the *wild magic surge* tables.

Comment: You should add to the metamagic rods that only one rod can be used on any spell. Sadly you cant stack them.

Answer (score 1):

## [Sacred Geometry](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/sacred-geometry/)

> When you take this feat, select two metamagic feats you do not yet have. When casting a spell, **you can perform the steps below to spontaneously apply the effects of either or both of these metamagic feats, as well as any other metamagic feats you have, to the spell without expending a higher-level spell slot**.

It's a fairly universally banned feat by GM's for the reason that it does such, but it is exactly what you want.

Comment: No, this is the reason it's banned: *"Then roll a number of d6s equal to the number of ranks you possess in Knowledge (engineering). **Perform some combination of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division upon the numbers rolled** that gives rise to one of the relevant prime constants."*

Comment: No, the slowdown does have some effect on why it's banned, but it really does not take that much time or add much to why it's banned. The real reason it's banned is because it gives casters a lot more power and lends to the C/MD issue. However, that's not a relevant SE topic.