# Haunted Heroes Pact Wizard may cause a favored spell combo to be even more broken?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, archetype

I've been looking at the Pact Wizard archetype from Haunted Heroes Handbook and noticed a feature they pick up at 10th level that states that when metamagic feats are applied to spells learned via patron or curse, the spells are treated with a spell of one level lower with a minimum level equal to the spell's original level).

Here's where the problem comes in.  A few patrons give Time Stop as their bonus patron spell at level 18.  In the PHB, the spell already specifies 1d4+1 rounds for how long the spell lasts.  2 to 5 rounds is pretty crazy already.  The metamagic feat that could make this spell completely broken is Extend Spell.  +1 to the spell's level and doubles the duration of the spell (as stated in the PHB), and with the aforementioned class feature, 4 to 10 rounds could get that kind of spell banned from a game table.

It goes from bad to worse when Delayed Blast Fireball comes into play; it can be charged for several rounds before being detonated.  Lots of players like spamming Grease to keep opponents at bay and make them easier to hit.  When you have 4 to 10 rounds to set up the battlefield and charge up that fire bomb, your GM could very well ban you from using Extend Spell in that manner.

So to elaborate on the question: does the feature even work that way for Time Stop?  Or does the extend only apply to the base +1 to make a +2 and then you roll?  For the sake of balance, I hope it's the latter.

EDIT: I double-checked the PHB.  The Delayed Blast Fireball can only be charged for 5 rounds before being detonated, but given the possible amount of turns that can be added with the rules confusion, it's possible to use a few turns to set up a large pool of Grease around enemies and then charge up a Delayed Blast Fireball, so while the damage won't be breaking, there can still be insane control beforehand, so it would be nice to clear up the amount of turns that Extend Spell would give Time Stop with the Pact Wizard class feature.

Comment: This question would be improved by quoting various applicable blocks of rules text - especially Extend Spell and the duration aspect of Time Stop.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). You should edit your question to read as if it were always the best version of itself; anyone interested in older revisions can view the revision history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- a pact wizard can extend the duration of *time stop*, and it doubles the duration.

There are lots of other ways to apply metamagic without increasing the spell level.  We have a question that lists some of those ways: [How can I reduce or ignore metamagic costs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128957/how-can-i-reduce-or-ignore-metamagic-costs)

This is a very good ability!  But it doesn't unlock until seventeenth level.  There are lots of very good abilities available at that time, and it's not obvious to me that this is so broken that we should worry about it specifically.

(Another way to say that might be: it's very difficult to play Pathfinder at very high levels, because so many characters have so many really good abilities.  Most games probably won't reach seventeenth level, and of the ones that do reach that level, this particular combo probably won't be their biggest concern.)

---

Incidentally, I don't think *delayed blast fireball* and *grease* would be the best use of a *time stop*.

Damage spells become increasingly impractical at high levels -- enemies have high hit points and good saves, and many of them have spell resistance or elemental immunities.  The [treantmonk guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xjPIOH8F8a0l74BdDF7Q23nCfZ-YX68Xr6JmmtznMw4/edit) has more text about this -- briefly, he thinks spellcasters should prefer control spells to damage spells.  Even from within a *time stop*, I would expect many characters would prefer to use *summon monster*, or to cast abjuration spells restricting their foes' movement, rather than go for the direct damage.

As to *grease*, many of the monsters you'll face at high levels will be able to jump, or fly, or phase, or will simply be too large to be inconvenienced by a 10-foot square on the ground.  It seems to me that a spell like *black tentacles* or *prismatic wall* would work better for someone who had access to *time stop*.

Comment: The asker may be assuming that the grease produced by the *grease* spell is flammable and thus increases the damage the fireballs deal, despite the lack of any rules text to support that theory.